# Text not aligning with large font-size

Tags: html, css

I'm building a periodic table in HTMl/CSS and I cant get the text inside the large `.element-symbol` to align left with the `.atomic-weight`, `.element-name` and `.atomic-symbol` without an arbitrary `text-indent`. I guess this is just to do with the width of the letters, but is there a way of having the first letter in `.element-symbol` start hard left? i.e against the red border

Markup:

```
<div class="cell">
  <div class="atomic-number"><span>2</span></div>
  <div class="element-symbol">      
    <abbr>He</abbr>
  </div>
  <div class="element-name"><span>Helium</span></div>
  <div class="atomic-weight">4.002602</div>
  </div>
```

CSS: (red borders to show alignment issue)

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 1;
  }

.cell {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 280px;
  height: 280px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding:10px;
  background-color: #4DBCE9;
  }

.element-symbol {
 font-size: 173px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 font-weight: 400;
 /*text-indent: -12px;  dont want to use this*/
 }

.atomic-number, .atomic-weight, .element-name {
 font-size: 25px;
 border: 1px solid red;
 }
```

[Example in codepen](http://codepen.io/andrewcowley/pen/AfpjJ)

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "start hard left"?

Comment: can you show image of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: If you look at the pen there's space between the H in the He and the red border. I want all the text to align on the left. but dont want to have to use a different text indent for every single element on the full table of elements

Comment: Sorry the question was unclear. I've edited it for clarity.

Comment: When building a table, why don’t you use the most logical and convenient markup, an HTML table?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Thanks for the input, this is a reduced test case to show the issue I'm having with the 'H' glyph. This is unrelated to the surrounding markup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each glyph in a font, sits within a bounding box. The glyph is usually not hard up against any of the edges of that box, and each glyph (or letter) will have differing amounts of space around it to help space it naturally when it is combined with other glyphs to form words.

Have a look at http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/glyphs/glyphs-3.html to get a feel for some of the intricacies of type design.

I'm not aware of any text or font properties in CSS that can eliminate that space, and in any case that space will be different for each glyph, and different between the same glyphs in different fonts.

Comment: Thanks for responding and the useful link.

Answer (score 3):

You're right - it's simply because of the size of the letters.

In most fonts, each character has a small amount of whitespace to either side of it, to separate it from adjacent letters. Without this space the letters would just run in to each other. At large font sizes, this space gets to be fairly significant, and produces the effect you're seeing. The only other option would be to find (or create) a font that doesn't have that space (or perhaps only has trailing space after each letter and no leading space).

Comment: Thanks, I thought this was the case. There seems to be a hack/fix for most things so I thought it worth asking the question!